# C#: Very easy calculator not working

Tags: c#

I'm a big noob to c# and I'm trying to make a very easy console application calculator that can only add. but I can't seem to figure out how it's not working. Here is the code. (error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to int.)

```
//first number
Console.WriteLine("First Number:");
string num1 = Console.ReadLine();

//second number
Console.WriteLine("Second Number:");
string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

int i = int.Parse(num1)+(num2);
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you have to parse both `num1` and `num2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `int.Parse` for second number

```
//first number
Console.WriteLine("First Number:");
string num1 = Console.ReadLine();

//second number
Console.WriteLine("Second Number:");
string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

int i = int.Parse(num1)+int.Parse(num2);
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
//first number
Console.WriteLine("First Number:");
string num1 = Console.ReadLine();

//second number
Console.WriteLine("Second Number:");
string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

int i = Convert.ToInt32(num1) + Convert.ToInt32(num2);

Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.ReadLine();
```